# Remove the blank space while viewing the item. using multiselect list box

Tags: infopath

In one InfoPath form ,I am using multiple selection list box, which is taking value from the list having 50 values. User can select any number of values for example 2.

After submitting the InfoPath form while I am viewing the item there is lot of blank spaces are coming because of list is  having 50 values and it is taking that all spaces while viewing the form.

Could you help me to remove that blank spaces.

Comment: Can you illustrate this with a partial screenshot and a fragment of HTML markup that shows the problematic item?